# Convert Numeric Ranges in a Dataframe to Character/Factor in R?

Tags: r

I have a big data frame (x) with numerical data; the first four lines look like this:

```
  A   B  C  D  E  F  G  H I  J  K   L   M  N  O   P  Q   R   S
1 -10  0  0  0 20 10 30 0 60 15 -10 -10 10 60 -10 60   0  60   0
2   0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 60 15 -10 -10 10 60 -10 60  15  60  60
3   0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 60 15 -10 -10 10 60 -10 60   0  60   0
4  10 20 30 40  0 10  0 0 60 15 -10 -10 10 60 -10  0 100 200 300
```

I want to replace the values with character following some rules:
S: 0-9
P: 10-14
L: 15-29
I: 30-59
R: >= 60

I tried:

```
x[x < 10] <- "S"
x[x > 9 & x < 15] <- "P"
x[x > 14 & x < 30] <- "L"
x[x > 29 & x < 60] <- "I"
x[x > 60] <- "R"
```

And I get this:

```
  A  B C D E F  G H I  J K L M N  O P  Q   R  S
1  R R R R R 10 R R 60 R R R R 60 R 60   R 60  R
2  R R R R R  R R R 60 R R R R 60 R 60   R 60 60
3  R R R R R  R R R 60 R R R R 60 R 60   R 60  R
4 10 R R R R 10 R R 60 R R R R 60 R  R 100  R  R
```

But when I tried:

```
x[x>60] <- 60
x[x<10] <- 0
x[x > 9 & x < 15] <- "P"
x[x == 0] <- "S"
x[x > 14 & x < 30] <- "L"
x[x > 29 & x < 60] <- "I"
x[x == 60] <- "R"
```

I got:

```
  A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S
1 S S S S L P I S R L S S P R S R S R S
2 S S S S S S S S R L S S P R S R L R R
3 S S S S S S S S R L S S P R S R S R S
4 P L I I S P S S R L S S P R S S R R R
```

Any hint on this outcomes and on how to achieve my goal properly?
Any suggestion is welcome

Comment: Look at `str(df)` before and after you execute each line of code in your first try. My guess is that it changes after the first call and in the subsequent calls x is no longer numeric.

Comment: What is your desired output out of these two? Can't you just do `df[] <- cut(unlist(df), c(-Inf, 10, 14, 29, 59, Inf), c("S", "P", "L", "I", "R"))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what happens here is once you call

```
x[x < 10] <- "S"
```

`x` is no longer integer but some columns become character. And then you start comparing characters and integers and this gives unexpected results:

```
> "I" > 60
[1] TRUE
```

There's a simple way out: create a new dataframe `y` in which you write your result:

```
y = x

y[x < 10] <- "S"
y[x > 9 & x < 15] <- "P"
y[x > 14 & x < 30] <- "L"
y[x > 29 & x < 60] <- "I"
y[x >= 60] <- "R"
```

Output:

```
> y
  A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S
1 S S S S L P I S R L S S P R S R S R S
2 S S S S S S S S R L S S P R S R L R R
3 S S S S S S S S R L S S P R S R S R S
4 P L I I S P S S R L S S P R S S R R R
```

Note that I changed one of your `>` to `>=` to include all cases.

Appendix: Data

```
xx = "  A   B  C  D  E  F  G  H I  J  K   L   M  N  O   P  Q   R   S
1 -10  0  0  0 20 10 30 0 60 15 -10 -10 10 60 -10 60   0  60   0
2   0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 60 15 -10 -10 10 60 -10 60  15  60  60
3   0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 60 15 -10 -10 10 60 -10 60   0  60   0
4  10 20 30 40  0 10  0 0 60 15 -10 -10 10 60 -10  0 100 200 300"
x = read.table(text = xx, header = T)
```

Comment: There is a built in function in R for such operations called `cut`. You can just do `df[] <- cut(unlist(df), c(-Inf, 9, 14, 29, 59, Inf), c("S", "P", "L", "I", "R"))`

Comment: @DavidArenburg thanks for pointing out. This solution is more flexible in case intervals are non-adjacent, but in that case I actually like the `ifelse` solution to the marked duplicate better.